# How to Receive response in XML format from CURL XML Request in PHP

Tags: php, xml, curl

I am trying to Send and receive the XML using curl in PHP. I want to try
   to connect the salesforce via curl request.
   But the problem which I am facing is that the response is a single 
   string, whereas salesforce returns the response in XML.

I am sending XML request to login into the saleforce. 
   Here is my script

```
$data='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>.....'


$tuCurl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/29.0");
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_PORT , 443);
/*curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,false);
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);*/
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);  
/*curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);*/
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/xml; 
charset=UTF- 8","SOAPAction: login", "Content-length: ".strlen($data)));
$tuData = curl_exec($tuCurl);
curl_close($tuCurl);
echo $tuData;

Thanks for any help!
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: Thanks but still response is in single string instead of XML.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should escape version and encoding on $data
e.g.

```
$data = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>".$whateverXml;
```